# Force ReadyBoost option for a disk (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, memory, readyboost

I have a RAM disk (Romex) that is reported to the system as a SCSI fixed disk. I want to use it for ReadyBoost. I am pretty sure it is fast enough for ReadyBoost. However, ReadyBoost tab does not appear in the properties of this disk. How can I force the system to use it for ReadyBoost?

Reason: I use Windows 32 version, which cannot access memory over the 3 GB threshold. However, this RAM disk is installed in the OS-invisible memory, which I want to use as disk cache via ReadyBoost.

Alternatives I tried:

- Direct-IO Romex RAM disk. ReadyBoost option is available, but when I try to use it, the error message says something like "Cannot create cache memory. Request not compatible." (my translation). I successfully use it for paging file.
- Romex PrimoCache. It seems it causes system instability (maybe incompatible with CrashPlan), so I disabled it. Note that the cache should be located in the OS-invisible memory. Anyway I would not like to mess with caching other than ReadyBoost, because I am not sure how it would be compatible with CrashPlan.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? ReadyBoost is a technology to work around lack of RAM. You obviously don't have that problem. Just use a 64-bit version of Windows.

Comment: @DanielB I am reluctant to change to 64 bits because some old programs that I still use will not work in it, and some drivers for older hardware that I use only exist for 32 bits. In a couple of years I probably will change to 64 bits, but it seems with a good RAM disk I can have the best of both worlds: old programs working and a fast enough system.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the RAM disk, I checked "[X] Disable NTFS indexing service" for this disk, and ReadyBoost tab did not appear. Now I re-created the disk leaving this box unchecked, and ReadyBoost tab has appeared in its Properties.